# How to make validation unique on date and some number column, but date only take year-month

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make unique rules on LARAVEL, that state if YYYY-MM and NUMBER_COLUMN is the same = return error/warning. but I only can make YYYY-MM-DD and NUMBER_COLUMN is the same = return error.

So, when I try to input the same number_column but a different day, it will get input into the table, I want that number_column cannot be the same in a month

MyCode:

```
$form->number('deed_number', 'Nomor Akta')->placeholder('Nomor Akta')
    ->creationRules(['required', "unique_month_date"])
    ->updateRules(['required', "unique_month_date"]);
$form->date('date', 'Tanggal Akta')->placeholder('Tgl Akta')->rules('required');
```

The table that I want:

```
NUMBER_COLUMN ; DATE_COLUMN

1 ; 2019-10-19 [Allowed]

2 ; 2019-10-19 [Allowed]

3 ; 2019-10-19 [Allowed]

3 ; 2019-10-20 [NotAllowed] <<< But it acceptable into database for current rule
```

deed_notary_numbers:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDeedNotaryNumbersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('deed_notary_numbers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->bigInteger('number')->unique();
            $table->integer('deed_number');
            $table->string('date');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->tinyInteger('creditor_id');
            $table->tinyInteger('creditor_manager_id');
            $table->tinyInteger('costumer_id');
            $table->tinyInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->longText('notes')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('deed_notary_numbers');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how "3" and "2019-10-20" could be the same

Comment: You'd probably need to [create your own validator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) to check if the value already exists for the given month (And maybe rephrase your question to make it clearer you "_want that number_column cannot be the same in a month_")

Comment: @Saly3301, for now, that could be the same, but I want to make it warning/error

The number_column could be the same if the month is different

Comment: @kerbholz okay, I would try to make a custom validator

Comment: @Saly3301 that because I made unique column [number, date] that's why "3" and "2019-10-19" ; "3" and "2019-10-20" can be input

Comment: Post your table migration

Comment: @Saly3301 that number column and date could not be the same in a month

Comment: I think I understand now, I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you don't want to allow a form to submit data where the number and date current month already exists

Trying to reproduce this, I came up with this solution

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Foo;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromDate($request->date);
        $month = $date->format('Y-m'); // Keep year attached
        $days = $date->daysInMonth;
        $request->validate([
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'number' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
                Rule::unique('foos')->where(function ($query) use ($request, $month, $days) {
                    return $query
                        ->whereBetween('date', ["$month-01", "{$month}-{$days}"])
                        ->whereNumber($request->number);
                }),
            ],
        ]);
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->date = $request->date;
        $foo->number = $request->number;
        $foo->save();
        return $foo;
    }
}
```

Given a form like this

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="date" name="date" value="2019-10-19"><br>
    <input type="number" name="number" value="3"><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

And a route like this

```php
Route::post('/', 'FooController@store');
```

And a table migration like this

```php
Schema::create('foos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->integer('number');
    $table->unique(['date', 'number']);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Results:

First time posting 10-19-2019 and 3 is valid
Second time posting the same in invalid
Posting 10-20-2019 and 3 is invalid (3 already exists with October)
Posting with a different number is valid
Posting 11-19-2019 and 3 is valid

Hope this helps

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QaJTDee
Based on your code, that's work for October but not for others month?

Comment: You have to have an empty database, and also show what your HTML looks like

Comment: Wait, I need to change var $month

Comment: The var $month based on my table query, it will check the Year-Month

Comment: I just tested all other months and it works just fine

Comment: I'm using encore/laravel-admin project for this laravel

Comment: Your controller looks okay, I guess the problem is with existing data or the HTML form

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VeyyNJe this is the $form that design the HTML form

Comment: Not useful, I would rather help you via teamviewer instead of playing this guessing game forever

Comment: I couldn't chat you, not enough reputation

Comment: Twitter too, I can't
Do you have discord or something?

Answer (score 0):

The second way to solve this problem that I found is,

Separate the column "date" from the requested form, then save it into NEW COLUMN that I named as "yyyy_mm" so it will save from:

"date" => "2019-10-21" to "yyyy-mm" => "2019-10".

Split date:

```
$splitDate = explode("-", $request->date);
$yearDate = $splitDate[0];
$monthDate = $splitDate[1];
```

Unique rule:

```
'deed_number' => [
    'required',
    'integer',
    Rule::unique('deed_notary_numbers')->where(function ($query) use ($request, $yearDate, $monthDate) {
        return $query
            ->where('yyyy_mm', "$yearDate-$monthDate")
            ->where('deed_number', $request->deed_number);
    })->ignore($id) // For UpdateRule cause it will said already in database if no ignore
```

And that solved my problem